# Start two instances of spyder with python2.7 and python3.4 in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, spyder

I would like to install two spyder: one is with python2.7 and the other is with python3.4

And I run the commands to install both:

```
pip install spyder
pip3 install spyder
```

But how to start it differently?

Because when I type

```
spyder
```

It just comes out spyder with python2.7

How to start spyder with python3.4?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to download spyder through pip3 but instead used `apt install spyder3` but hopefully this will still work:

**For python2.7**

```
spyder
```

**For python3.4**

```
spyder3
```

I could get both running at the same time but if you have a problem try it with `--new-instance`

Hope that helps!